# Forking writes with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm interested in using Spring Data MongoDB to persist the same model to two different collections, and using Querydsl to query from both collections.

From my research, this doesn't seem possible with two separate repositories. Spring Data MongoDB doesn't seem to provide a way to override the collection name for a given repository.

Instead, The [MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) class has the option to specify a collection name as the last parameter for most of its methods, so I tried implementing a custom repository backed by a MongoTemplate. However, my repository would also have to implement the [QueryDslPredicateExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html) interface, and it's not immediately apparent how to map the Querydsl Predicate parameter to the Spring Data MongoDb Query parameter expected by the MongoTemplate.

Is there a way to specify the collection for a repository to use? If there is, that's the solution I'd like to use.

If not, is there any way to get the MongoTemplate to play nice with Querydsl?